# intent keeps crashing my app?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, crash

I'm building a simple menu app for my class. I have a ListView on my app and I am trying to make it so that when you click an item in the the list you are taken to the appropiate activity for that item. So far I got intents working outside my function but when I run it inside a function it crashes my program. can any one point me out in the right direction

```
    //set the item listener
    menu.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            String selected = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.complaint)).getText().toString();
            if(selected.equals("Pasta")){
                runPasta();
            }
        }
    });


}

public void runPasta(){
    //Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, PastaItems.class);
    //myIntent.putStringArrayListExtra("finalList", foodList);
    this.startActivity(new Intent(this,PastaItems.class));

}
```

Comment: share your log cat here

Comment: Dear, if you are asking for crashing then every-time you should post your crash-logs for better solution...

Answer (score 4):

You're calling the `runPasta()` function from inside the `OnItemClickListener` which means that `this` refers to the `OnItemClickListener` instance. Try using `ActivityClassName.this` instead of just `this`.

Answer (score 4):

You are using `this` as a `context`, it wont work inside `setOnItemClickListener` because it creates an **anonymous inner class**. 
So you need to be more specific.
Replace **this** with **YourActivity.this**

Answer (score 0):

This might solve your problem. Using **getContext()** gives you the appropriate context.
Try this :

```
startActivity(new Intent(getContext(),PastaItems.class));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the instance on `adapterView` to runPasta method and from runPasta method, you can call it `startActivity(new Intent(adapterView.getContext(),PastaItems.class));`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have declared the **PastaItems** Activity in your manifest.